# why map operator result is assigned to an array?

Tags: angular, dictionary, rxjs, observable, variable-assignment

my concern is about this piece of code

```
    export class RatingInputComponent {
      stars: boolean[] = Array(5).fill(false);
      get value(): number {
        return this.stars.reduce((total, starred) => {
          return total + (starred ? 1 : 0);
    }, 0);
  }
  rate(rating: number) {
    this.stars = this.stars.map((_, i) => rating > i);
  }
```

the map operator is supposed to return an observable but the result is assigned to an array, shoudn't the result assigned to an observable
thnaks

Comment: No observables here. Map is (also) just a normal array operator.

Comment: If you want an observable use of. `stars = of(Array(5).fill(false))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are confusing map(): An array method, and map(), the RXJS method. Obviously your bunch of code is using the array method. Same goes for reduce as used here.